# Matching Closest End Date to Start Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityHX (
ITEM_ID         nvarchar(5),
LINE            nvarchar(2),
ACTIVITY_DATE   date,
ACTIVITY        nvarchar(8)
);

INSERT INTO ActivityHX (ITEM_ID, LINE, ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY)

VALUES

('38003', '1', '20230803', 'OPENED'),
('38003', '2', '20230803', 'CLOSED'),
('38003', '3', '20230812', 'REOPENED'),
('38003', '4', '20230814', 'CLOSED')
('47155', '1', '20230805', 'OPENED'),
('47155', '2', '20230805', 'CLOSED'),
('47155', '3', '20230805', 'REOPENED'),
('47155', '4', '20230819', 'CLOSED');
```

that gives this result:

| ITEM_ID | LINE | ACTIVITY_DATE | ACTIVITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38003 | 1 | 2023-08-03 | OPENED |
| 38003 | 2 | 2023-08-03 | CLOSED |
| 38003 | 3 | 2023-08-12 | REOPENED |
| 38003 | 4 | 2023-08-14 | CLOSED |
| 47155 | 1 | 2023-08-05 | OPENED |
| 47155 | 2 | 2023-08-05 | CLOSED |
| 47155 | 3 | 2023-08-05 | REOPENED |
| 47155 | 4 | 2023-08-19 | CLOSED |

I started a Fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/f9tBIRFz. I am trying to figure out how to get my data to look like this:

| ITEM_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38003 | 2023-08-03 | 2023-08-03 |
| 38003 | 2023-08-12 | 2023-08-14 |
| 47155 | 2023-08-05 | 2023-08-05 |
| 47155 | 2023-08-05 | 2023-08-19 |

My data is simple and follows a clean order where most of the items have just one open and closed date. However, when I have items that have multiple reopened dates, I know the next line will be a closed activity. I am trying to solve on how to transpose the data to a start and end date columns without getting NULLS. When I try to use ROW_NUMBER(), I get NULLS even if I try to use CASE statements in it.

```
SELECT
 ITEM_ID
,CASE WHEN ACTIVITY IN ('OPENED', 'REOPENED') THEN ACTIVITY_DATE END 'START_DATE'
,CASE WHEN ACTIVITY = 'CLOSED' THEN ACTIVITY_DATE END 'END_DATE'
FROM (
SELECT
 ITEM_ID
,LINE
,ACTIVITY_DATE
,ACTIVITY
,Diff as 'Days Diff'
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Diff <= 0 then -1 else 1 end, abs(Diff)) as RN
from mydata) ActivityHX
```

I have searched various solutions and tried to piece this together, but I can't get the table to flatten to two rows only. Thanks for any suggestions.

Note: I updated the question by adding a scenario I ran into after the first suggestion helped tremedously. It turns out that I have data that reopens the same day it was closed. However, these same day reopens are showing up with the original closed date instead of the closed date associated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ITEM_ID,A.ACTIVITY_DATE AS START_DATE,CL_QUERY.ACTIVITY_DATE AS END_DATE
 FROM ActivityHX AS A
 OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 X.ACTIVITY_DATE 
     FROM ActivityHX AS X
     WHERE A.ITEM_ID=X.ITEM_ID AND X.ACTIVITY IN('CLOSED')
     AND A.ACTIVITY_DATE<=X.ACTIVITY_DATE
     ORDER BY X.ACTIVITY_DATE
  )CL_QUERY
  WHERE A.ACTIVITY IN('OPENED','REOPENED')
```

Please try this one

Comment: Thank you Sergey! This is the one I used as it was the easiest, however, I discovered that I have items that open and reopen the same day. I updated my question with this example.

Comment: I think I solved it by changing on Line 8,  AND A.ACTIVITY_DATE <= X.ACTIVITY_DATE to  AND A.ACTIVITY_DATE < X.ACTIVITY_DATE

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should get you there. There's possibly some edge cases I didn't think of but you can test with a larger sample size and get back to me:

```
with ActivityHX_Joined as
(
    select ahx1.ITEM_ID
        , ahx1.ACTIVITY_DATE START_DATE
        , ahx2.ACTIVITY_DATE END_DATE
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ahx1.ITEM_ID, ahx1.ACTIVITY_DATE order by ahx2.ACTIVITY_DATE) CLOSEST
    from ActivityHX ahx1
    inner join ActivityHX ahx2
        on ahx1.ITEM_ID = ahx2.ITEM_ID
        and ahx1.ACTIVITY in ('OPENED', 'REOPENED')
        and ahx2.ACTIVITY in ('CLOSED')
        and ahx1.ACTIVITY_DATE <= ahx2.ACTIVITY_DATE
)
select ahxj.ITEM_ID
    , ahxj.START_DATE
    , ahxj.END_DATE
from ActivityHX_Joined ahxj
where ahxj.CLOSEST= 1
```

Basically, we self join the table with the left hand table being the `OPENED` or `REOPENED` lines, and the right hand table being the `CLOSED` lines. Then we make sure the `CLOSED` records are the same date or later as the `OPENED`/`REOPENED` records. After that, we use a window function to calculate the closest end date for our open record and select that row.

## Hacky Way to Handle Same Date

```
select ahx1.ITEM_ID
    , ahx1.ACTIVITY_DATE START_DATE
    , ahx2.ACTIVITY_DATE END_DATE
from ActivityHX ahx1
inner join ActivityHX ahx2
    on ahx1.ITEM_ID = ahx2.ITEM_ID
    and ahx1.LINE = ahx2.LINE - 1
    and ahx2.ACTIVITY in ('CLOSED') --this line is not necessarily needed if the LINE column always increments by 1 from OPENED/REOPENED to CLOSED
where ahx1.ACTIVITY in ('OPENED', 'REOPENED')
```

Comment: Thank you, @Austin! Initially, this did not work as it return no data. Then I noticed that in the ROW_NUMBER() line, we needed to add the ahx1.ITEM_ID to the PARTITION BY. I did that and boom - that worked too! Thank you!

Comment: So, follow up..... discovered that I have data that reopened on the same day it end. For example, I would have an item that started 8-14-22 and ended same day. Then later in the day, it reopened and then closed a few days later. How would I account for restart/reopened that occurred same day?

Comment: Thanks Austin. Actually, I have about 8 different activities in addition to OPENED, REOPENED, and CLOSED. So, the LINE will not always increment by 1s, the REOPENED and CLOSED (and "RECLOSED") will always follow in the order.

Comment: Yes, I am out of luck. There is no other incremental field. Can't use the LINE numbers as I only need 3 of the 8. And can't use the DATETIME stamp because I have instances where the times are absolutely identical (this is system generated in night jobs - I begged them to add at least 1 second to next line, but no one listens). Given that, I am going to try figure out how to evaluate preceding row DATETIME and if they're equal to give it 1 second.

Comment: I actually found a LAG that has potential. I did add more rows above to highlight the issue I found and trying to solve for.

Comment: Austin - I solved the issue with CLOSED date being identical to REOPENED date by do an initial CTE using LAG() to sort and add 1 second if any of the DTTMs of the ITEM_ID and LINE # had matching times. With that, I then used it to your solution and it works except that with using an INNER JOIN it leaves out the END_DATEs that are NULL. If I switch it to LEFT JOIN, then I get all the END_DATE returned as START_DATE.

Comment: Austin - Figured out the missing NULLS. I moved the JOIN ON for the different activities to their own CTEs and then joined them back to the subquery you designed. Works perfect now and everything lines up great. Thanks for your help!